# Subject and Predicate Agreement with " Половина"

Tags: грамматика

Когда мы приехали в город, половина магазинов (не работала,работали, работало).

Which variant sounds more natural to your ear? Because I believe that more than one is correct

Answer (score 2):

Грамматически верно "не работала" и "работала", так как относится к "половине" но в речи встречается и остальные вариации, где "работали", "работало". Лично по мне, "работали" и "не работали" звучат наименее гладко.

Comment: I looked through examples on ruscorpora com and noticed both singular and plural endings, no matter present or past tense used, with the ending -о used after не менее половины магазинов...

Comment: Can you add the rule?

Comment: @V.V. It is not a rule, it is just an agreement in grammatical case. I think (just my opinion), that it is a mixture of subcases being used for animate and inanimate objects. I.e. "Сесть на диван" but "сесть на барана". Same here, "человек работал" and "магазин работал" strictly speaking are two different words, first was doing something and second was in availability state.